# Dividir List com mais de mil linhas - .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, lista

Estou recebendo um erro ao realizar este select

```
sb = New StringBuilder
sb.Append(" SELECT  ")
sb.Append(" SE.NU_SERIE_NF, ")
sb.Append(" SE.NU_NF, ")
sb.Append(" SE.DH_ENTREGA, ")
sb.Append(" SE.DH_IMPORTACAO, ")
sb.Append(" SE.ARMAZEM, ")
sb.Append(" SE.TRANSPORTADORA ")
sb.Append(" FROM ")
sb.Append(" SEP_ENTREGA SE ")
sb.Append(" WHERE ")
sb.Append(" SE.NU_NF IN (" & nuNota.ToString() & ") AND ")
sb.Append(" SE.NU_SERIE_NF IN (" & nuSerieNota.Distinct().ToList().FirstOrDefault().ToString() & ") ")
dtEmail = ListarDados(sb.ToString, conexao)
```

O erro acontece nesta linha `sb.Append(" SE.NU_NF IN (" & nuNota.ToString() & ") AND ")` pelo resultado ter mil linhas ou mais, coisa que o select no Oracle não aceita.

Código que popula a variável `nuNota`:

```
'Monta lista com os Números de Nota
 Dim nuNota As String = ""
 Dim nuSerieNota As String = ""
 For i As Integer = 0 To listaNotaDHSolColeta.Count - 1
          nuNota += listaNotaDHSolColeta.Item(i).nuNota.ToString()
          nuSerieNota += listaNotaDHSolColeta.Item(i).nuSerieNota.ToString()
          If i < listaNotaDHSolColeta.Count - 1 Then
             nuNota += ","
             nuSerieNota += ","
          End If
 Next
```

Procurei na net, mas não consegui resolver esse problema.

A minha dúvida é, como posso dividir essa lista em 2 partes, para que eu possa buscar no select ?

Comment: Em vb não sei muito se tem, mas algo como um count() teria o tamanho total da lista basta dividi por 2 e depois fazer a busca dos dados até esse ponto algo como o .Take() do c#.

Comment: Esta é uma dúvida apenas sobre Oracle. Não tem relação com .NET. Recomendo editar a pergunta afim de conseguir uma ajuda mais acertiva.

Comment: Discordo, a dúvida envolve ambos os lados. Já que a divisão que não estou conseguindo fazer é diretamente no código.

Comment: Tentou trocar a lista IN pelo SELECT (se for o caso) que a gera ? Algo como ....select .... from .... where ... campo in (select campo from .....)

Answer (score 1):

Em princípio, me parece que a solução indicata por [Motta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5005/motta) seria a mais adequada (no caso de os elementos em `listaNotaDHSolColeta` também estarem vindo de uma consulta à base de dados).

Em todo caso, se seu intuito é realizar a consulta em etapas, cada uma delas com um grupo de "n" números de nota, seu ponto de partida é dividir seu array em grupos de "n" elementos. Você pode usar a função abaixo para fazer isso (como não sei o tipo de `listaNotaDHSolColeta`, fiz a função genérica, mas poderia também ter usado o tipo `Object`):

```
Function Pacotes(Of T)(lista As IEnumerable(Of T), elementos As Integer) As T()()
    Dim dicItens As New Dictionary(Of Integer, T), dicGrupos As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of T)), iGrupo As Integer
    For Each item As T In lista
        dicItens(dicItens.Count) = item
    Next
    For Each kvpItem As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, T) In dicItens
        iGrupo = kvpItem.Key \ elementos
        If Not dicGrupos.ContainsKey(iGrupo) Then
            dicGrupos(iGrupo) = New List(Of T)
        End If
        dicGrupos(iGrupo).Add(kvpItem.Value)
    Next
    Return dicGrupos.Select(Function(kvp) kvp.Value.ToArray).ToArray
End Function
```

Você pode utilizá-la assim:

```
Dim gruposNotaDHSolColeta = Pacotes(listaNotaDHSolColeta, 1000)
```